# prompt box can't popup again after it disappeared

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to popup a prompt box when user click trash button. But whatever I clicked in the  prompt box, it can't popup again after box disappeared.

HTML:

```
<div class="prompt" id="del_product" style="display:none;">
        <p>Do you confirm to delete product?</p>
        <a class="promptBtn" id="cancel_del">Cancel</a>
        <a class="promptBtn" id="confirm_del">OK</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(".delbtn").click(function(){
        $('#del_product').show()
    });

    $('#cancel_del').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide()
    });

    $('#confirm_del').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide()
        //....will do something

    });
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Well this will not work: `$('#confrim_del').click(function(){` The id is a typo and also  `$(this).parent.hide()` is wrong.

Comment: Nothing in that code should not keep it from showing.

Comment: `$(this).parent.hide()` should be `$(this).parent().hide()`. Moreover, I do not understand what the problem is. It shows multiple times: http://jsfiddle.net/dxzzeLso/

Comment: Yes, It's a typo in the question. I've correct it. But it still not work

Comment: I've found the root cause. It's removed from dom by another jquery

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** generally, it is better practice to not hide the `.parent()`, but the `.closest('.prompt')` or closest with '#del_product' ...
Prevents issues, where additional tags might be included by either you or the browser. Or a CMS.